# For all $P\in S$ there is a line $L\subset S$ containing $P$. Then $S$ is a ruled surface.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, projective-geometry

Here is exercise (10), chapter 3, from Beauville's *Complex Algebraic Surfaces*:

> Let $S\subset\Bbb{P}^3$ be a surface, not necessarily smooth, such that every point of $S$ lies on a line contained in $S$. Show that $S$ is birationally isomorphic to a ruled surface. Conversely show that every ruled surface is birational to a surface of the preceding type (and more precisely, we can take this to be a cone in $\Bbb{P}^3$)

My questions are:

1. I'm bothered by the way he phrased it. By Beauville's definition, a ruled surface is a surface birationally equivalent to $C\times\Bbb{P}^1$. Therefore, to say that $S$ is birationally equivalent to a ruled surface wouldn't be equivalent to say that $S$ is a ruled surface? Why didn't he simply say "show that $S$ is ruled"?
2. Isn't the converse obvious? I mean, a ruled surface is birational to $C\times\Bbb{P}^1$, and it's easy (at least easy to imagine how) to construct a cone in $\Bbb{P}^3$ birational to $C\times\Bbb{P}^1$ which has the property described in the question.
3. If $S$ has the mentioned property, I guess in order to prove it is birational to $C\times\Bbb{P}^1$ we should be able to find something that looks like a fibration $S\to C$ with fibres that look like $\Bbb{P}^1$, but I'm not sure how. It would be nice, for example, to find a curve $C\subset S$ such that through each $P\in C$ there is only one line $L\subset S$ passing through $P$. But it obviously doesn't work always.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Projective plane is birationally ruled, but not of the form $C\times \mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @Mohan, yes, I'm aware of that. But I don't see how this helps in this case.

Comment: @Mohan, by the way, Beauville defines a ruled surface as a surface birationally equivalent to $C\times\Bbb{P}^1$

Comment: Typically ruled means you have a ruling, that is a morphism to a projective curve with general (some times all) fibers projective lines.

Comment: @rmdmc89 the idea is to take a hyperplane section and use the assumption that a general point lies on a *unique* line (this will take some justification/dealing with quadrics separately [i.e. show that any surface with two lines through a general point is a smooth quadric]) to define a rational map from $S$ to the hyperplane section. And yes, I think the converse is basically obvious since the birational equivalence class of a ruled surface is, basically by definition, determined by $C$ and vice-versa. I don't think there are any subtleties in constructing the cone over $C$.

Comment: As for the terminology issue, wasn't the book translated by somebody other than Beauville? There is always the opportunity for errors to arise in the process of translation.

Comment: @TabesBridges, I know that if $S$ has degree $d$, then every line $L\subset S$ has $L^2=2-d$. In particular, $d\geq 3$ implies $L^2<0$. Does that help me to prove what you said about two lines in a general point?

Comment: @TabesBridges, what I said proves that for $d\geq 3$, a hyperplane section cannot be of the form $H=L_1+L_2$ where $L_1,L_2$ are lines. But what if $H=L_1+L_2+D$ for some other $D$?

Comment: @TabesBridges, I'm not sure I know how to treat the "general point" condition

Comment: This is non-rigorous and I haven't had my coffee yet, but: if you have two lines $L_1,L_2$ through a general point $x$, then you can translate along $L_1$ to another general point $x'$ and find another line $L_2'$. Then $L_2\cdot L_2'$ should 1) "realize" the intersection number $L_2^2$, and 2) be non-negative.

Comment: Now to do this properly with Cartier divisors, let $L_1 + L_2 + D$ be a hyperplane section and vary it in the pencil of hyperplanes containing $L_1$. Either another hyperplane section has the form $L_1 + L_2' + D'$ and you can run the argument above, or $L_2+D$ deforms to something irreducible and you have a unique line through a general point. Does this help at all?